# VBA Error Message - Method 'Range' of Object _Global' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code where I'm receiving a "'Range' of Object _Global' failed" error and I'm hoping someone can help as to why. I've looked online and everything seems to advise that I need to specific which sheet the code is referring to, which i've done using With and End With. Please see my code below;

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables")
Range(StartingPoint, EndPoint).Copy
End With
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. The variables specified above this code are as follows;

```
Dim ws7 As Worksheet
Set ws7 = ActiveSheet

Dim StartingPoint As Range
Dim EndPoint As Range
Set StartingPoint = Sheets("Tables").Range("C58:R58").Find(ws7.Range("C3"))
If Not StartingPoint Is Nothing Then
Set EndPoint = StartingPoint.Offset(10, 0)
End If
```

Any help and / or useful reading material would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the erroring part come in the code, do you check startpoint and endpoint before using?

Comment: It's the Range within the With / End With piece on the first set of code where's it falling over.

Comment: Just a quick comment: Besides from the full stop @Rory suggested in his answer, are you sure that StartingPoint is getting set to anything, because if it is not, then EndPoint will never get set, therefore failing.

Comment: I've ran the StartingPoint code entirely on its own, adding a copy request in, and it's doing exactly what it should be which indicates it's something to do with the EndPoint?

Answer (score 1):

Your `With` statement is not currently doing anything as you haven't qualified the `Range` call - it needs to be:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables")
.Range(StartingPoint, EndPoint).Copy
End With
```

Note the full stop in `.Range`

Also, this assumes those two ranges are on the Tables sheet, or the code will fail.

Comment: Thanks @Rory. I've done that, and am now getting an error saying "Application-defined or Object-defined error". Aren't StartingPoint / EndPoint being defined using the Dim / Set coding though?

Comment: Are those two ranges on the Tables sheet?

Comment: Yes, the first range determines parameter 1, but it is also called on to determine parameter 2, the idea being that both together provide the range. So yes, both ranges are on the Tables sheet.

Comment: Are you certain of that? What does `Msgbox StartingPoint.Parent.Name` display?

Comment: I was, not so much now though. But if I change it to specify the Tables sheets through `Set StartingPoint = Sheets("Tables").Range("C58:R58").Find(ws7.Range("C3"))` that should suffice shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes that ought to do it.